# Vim on git bash on window(MINGW64) automatically break line on commit message

Tags: bash, git, vim, mingw-w64

I'm working on Windows platform and using git bash on 'MINGW64' installed with git.

I don't remember when but there is something unfamiliar feature for me was updated to my terminal that automatically insert an newline while writing git commit message with Vim.

I'm currently using some hooks with my commit message and the form is fit with my old style so I don't need this fancy feature right now.

but I couldn't find any option to off this.
How can I off this?

Please help me~

Comment: Try  to run vim without plugins (`vi --noplugin`) or without vimrc  (`vi -u NORC`).  For more info see `:help  --noplugin`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Vim 7.4, the `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/gitcommit.vim` forces hard wrapping to `'textwidth'`, by setting `'formatoptions'`, in particular the `t` value which *auto-wraps text using textwidth*.

To undo this, place either of the following commands into `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/gitcommit.vim`:

```
setlocal formatoptions-=t
```

or

```
setlocal formatoptions<
```

Comment: The option needed was just 'set tw=0'. but actually it was not work on my .vimrc at home dir. But as I replaced it into '~/.vim/after/ftplugin/gitcommit.vim'. now it works. I don't know why but anyway I'm happy now.

Comment: Yes, resetting `'textwidth'` is another option to solve this. However, by clearing that you're also not able to _manually_ reformat blocks (e.g. with the `gq` command).